# I am trying to make a social media app. How do I connect my app to a mySql and, Xampp?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

Here is my code for my register java:

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

Button bRR;
EditText etFN, etLN, etEmail, etUN, etPW, etRPW;
Spinner SMonth, SDay, SYaer;
TextView TVterms;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    initTypeface();

    //Button's go here
    bRR = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bRR);

    bRR = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bRR);
    bRR.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf"));
    //EditText's go here
    etFN = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFN);
    etLN = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etLN);
    etEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etUN = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUN);
    etPW = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPW);
    etRPW = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etRPW);
    //Spinner's go here
    SMonth = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SMonth);
    SDay = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SDay);
    SYaer = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SYear);

    SMonth = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SMonth);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Month, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    SMonth.setAdapter(adapter);

    SDay = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SDay);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Day, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    SDay.setAdapter(adapter);

    SYaer = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SYear);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Year, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    SYaer.setAdapter(adapter);
    //TextView's go here
    TVterms = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVterms);
}
public void onSignUpClick(View v)
{
    if (v.getId() == R.id.bRR);
    {
        EditText fname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFN);
        EditText lname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etLN);
        EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUN);
        EditText email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        EditText pass1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPW);
        EditText pass2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etRPW);

        String fnamestr = fname.getText().toString();
        String lnamestr = lname.getText().toString();
        String unamestr = uname.getText().toString();
        String emailstr = email.getText().toString();
        String pass1str = pass1.getText().toString();
        String pass2str = pass2.getText().toString();

        if (!pass1str.equals(pass2str))
        {
            //popup msg
            Toast pass = Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Password do not match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            pass.show();

        }

    }
}

private void initTypeface() {

    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    TextView tittleText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    tittleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    tittleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    tittleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    tittleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    tittleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    tittleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    tittleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    tittleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVterms);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);
}
}
```

I want to store the st name, last name, username, email, date of birth and password. How do I do that. I can't to the tutorials on this because ArrayList NameValuePair has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create php web services which sends output in JSON format.
In adroid app i recommend you to use android volley library.

Volley is an HTTP library that makes networking for Android apps easier and most importantly, faster. Volley is available through the open AOSP repository.

[Read more about volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)
Also here is tutorial about volley and mysql connection [Volley mysql](http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/12/android-php-insert-mysql-db-volley.html)

Comment: HEY THANKS! But I'm new to android so I'm kinda lost. Would you mind giving me an example bud? Here's my email. IsaacMedinaXbox360-live@hotmail.com. I would really appreciate. Thanks !!! @Adnan

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Volley library, you can also use Retrofit library and see its tutorials, [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html) tutorial is really helpful. These 2 libraries are currently the most used libraries helping server client communication.

If you do not want to use a 3rd party library, you can use AsyncTasks in your Activity. [This](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) can be a good starting tutorial if you are new to php mysql integration. Wamp and xammp are similar, you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: THANKS BRO!! But wasn't AsyncTasks deprecated?

Comment: I prefer using retrofit, it was easier for me to integrate then volley. AsyncTasks have also some disadvantages which are mentioned in http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html.